# SQL - compare multiple rows and return rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large database and i'd like to pull info from a table (Term) where the Names are not linked to a PartyId for a certain SearchId. However:

1. There are multiple versions of the searches (sometimes 20-40 - otherwise I think [SQL - Comparing two rows and two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664229/sql-comparing-two-rows-and-two-columns) would work for me)
2. The PartyId will almost always be NULL for the first version for the search, and if the same Name for the same SearchId has a PartyId associated in a later version the NULL row should not appear in the results of the query.
3. I have 8 left joins to display the information requested - 3 of them are joined on the Term table

A very simplified sample of data is below

CASE statement? Join the table with itself for comparison? A temp table or do I just return the fields I'm joining on and/or want to display?

[image: sample Term grid]

Comment: Generally wise to 1) post data structure, 2) define problem 3) post expected results.  1 and 2ish are done... expected results would help clairify your question.  also please define the database (mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle postgresql else?)  as not all engines support all the same functions and syntax.

Comment: correlated subquery with not exists.  Define a set which matches the criteria then correlate that to your base set for not exists which would give you those terms which do not have a searchversID and partyId in the set you're looking for.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: apologies for the lack of information. my db is SQL 2012 RS management studio is SQL 2016. the expected result above would be nothing. only if NULL was found as a PartyId after the first version would the Name and SearchId be returned.

Comment: also i'm not quite clear about 'defining a set which matches the criteria' would entail. Logically (in english) it would be something like

Comment: @xQbert - unfortunately i'm not quite clear about 'defining a set which matches the criteria' would entail. Logically (in english) it would be something like If for any 2 rows Name1=Name2 and SearchId1=SearchID2 and retrieve the Name and SearchId if the PartyId IS NULL but the SearchVersId is not the lowest number where SearchId1=SearchID2 ... or perhaps it would be easier to say do not return a result for each Name where the SearchId is the same if there ever exists a PartyId otherwise return the Name and SearchId ... there are over 1.3 mil records

Comment: I don't understand the problem yet.  If you're after all the names for a searchID with a partyID of null... `SELECT Name from term where SearchID = 2 and PartyID is null; but that seems to simple since you have a searchversion of 2 for the same names I think you're after only those names whose highest search version has a partyID of null... so ... maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Providing sample data that yields no expected result is not as useful as providing data that gives an expected result..

When asking a question start with defining the problem in plain English.  If you can't you don't understand your problem well enough yet. Then define the tables which are involved in the problem (including the columns) and sample data; the SQL you've tried, and what you're expected result is using the data in your sample.  Without this minimum information we make many guesses and even with that information we may have to make assumptions; but without a minimum verifiable example showing illustrating your question, helping is problematic.

--End soap box

I'm guessing you're after only the names for a searchID which has a NULL partyID for the highest SearchVerID

So if we eliminated ID 6 from your example data, then 'Bob' would be returned
If we added ID 9 to your sample data for name 'Harry' with a searchID of 2 and a searchVerID of 3 and a null partyID then 'Harry' too would be returned...
If my understanding is correct, then perhaps...

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Name, Row_Number() over (partition by Name order by SearchVersID Desc)
  FROM Term
  WHERE SearchID = 2)
SELECT Name 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 
  and partyID is null;
```

This assigns a row number (RN) to each name starting at 1 and increasing by one for each entry; for searchID's of 2.  The highest searchversion will always have a RN of  1.  Then we filter to include only those RN which are 1 and have a null partyID. This would result in only those names having a searchID of 2 the highest search version and a NULL partyID

Ok So I took the question a different way too..

If you simply want all the names not linked to a PartyID for a given search.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TERM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TERM B 
                  WHERE A.Name = B.Name 
                    AND SearchID = 2) and partyID is not null)
AND searchID = 2
```

The above should return all term records associated to searchID 2 
that have a partyId.  This last method is the exists not exists and set logic I was talking about in comments.

Comment: thank you for the information. Since it seems I have been negligent in providing enough information, I withdraw my query until I can better form my question. apologies for wasting your time.